# How to get file path of currently playing song in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to get currently playing song's **file path** in android. I have tried lots of solutions and I have also answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34269021/4583544). 
But after a while I understand that sometimes track names are not standard and there may be tracks with same name. So my methods will not work here because it get confused that which of the songs to return and it will return same path for all songs with same name.
After that I tried to query songs by combination of multiple intent values like this:

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " == \"" + intent.getStringExtra("track") + "\""
" and "+MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + " == \"" + intent.getLongExtra("duration") + "\"";
```

because it's rarely possible that a song with same name and duration exists. But again there is another problem that all players don't return **duration** of songs.

I have also searched allot to find a general solution and get currently playing song's path from android core independent of which player is playing(I think there must be somewhere that handle all of this and I can get what I want there), but I can't find any solution.I'm really confused!!

Is there any general way to get playing song path from android without knowing the player?Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any general way to get playing song path from android without knowing the player?

No.

First, there is no requirement for a player to be playing songs that are stored locally on the device. There are many streaming audio players, for example.

Second, even if the player is playing a song that happens to be stored locally, there is no requirement for a player to tell other applications, by any means, what song is being played.

Third, even if the player is playing a song that happens to be stored locally and happens to leak information about what is playing, there is no requirement that the path to that file be somewhere that your app can discover. You seem to be assuming that all songs are indexed by `MediaStore`, and that is not always the case.

Fourth, even if the player is playing a song that happens to be stored locally, happens to leak information about what is playing, *and* happens to be indexed by `MediaStore`, there is no requirement that your app be able to access that file via the filesystem. For example, that file might be on removable storage.

Comment: I have tried to handle this by using players returning value but as I said it has errors. So you say there is no way I can get the song file path without errors? :(

Comment: @Nahid: Some of the players that you hard-coded are streaming media players. There is no song file path, because the file is on a server somewhere, not on the device.

Comment: @CommonWare: yes. you are right, but what about files that are on the device?

Comment: @Nahid: That is covered in the "Third" and "Fourth" items from my answer.

Comment: @CommonWare: yes. I understand. Since I have spend allot of times on this it has really embarrassed me and I'm really looking to find a solution. Thanks for your answer. :)